# It's possible to use gitflow and pull request on sourcetree?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, pull-request

I'm new using Git. At work we usually use **Merge Requests** process (on GitLab, it's like a **Pull Request** on Git I think).

Now we want to use **GitFlow** and it seemed all right, but when a develop use **Finish Feature** on flow, the merge is automatic instead of using the pull requests.

We work on **SourceTree** UI, it's possible to use/configure the **Finish Feature** to do a **Pull Request**?

[image]

I saw a same question on [Atlassian Site](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/How-do-I-use-Git-Flow-to-make-pull-requests/qaq-p/74707) but no answer yet

Answer (score 1):

In SourceTree there is a menu item under Repository > "Create Pull Request ...", where you select your feature branch and will then open the bitbucket website. On the Bitbucket Webpage you can assign it to reviewers.

Comment: Here we use Gitlab instead of Bitbucket, I don't know if we can configure sourcetree to open gitlab pull request site. But, even it's possible, creating that pull request will end my git flow like click in Finish Feature?

Comment: no the feature branch will continue to exist until the pull request was accepted. You will have to switch to the develop branch yourself.